# How actually dangerous was RTLS for the Space Shuttle?

Tags: space-shuttle, safety, abort

I know that the Space Shuttle's Return To Launch Site abort mode was always considered to be particularly risky, and as a result was never tested. In particular, it seems like it requires everything to go properly in an even tighter envelope than the normal space shuttle launch, with serious problems to occur if the thing that caused the abort in the first place persists or deteriorates.

How risky is it, though? I've heard claims that it was *unlikely to work* or "constituted committing suicide to avoid being killed", or that it was a political/institutional fig leaf concealing a 'black zone'. However, this rarely seems to have much evidence behind it.

Is there any basis for estimation of how dangerous it was, either in the case of a perfectly working vehicle or in the case of failures that would *lead to* an RTLS?

Comment: I got to sit in on an RTLS sim in the SAIL (Shuttle Avionics Integration Laboratory) simulator. Actually OV-95 was a non-flying orbiter, not just a simulator. Unlike a sim where an instructor throws in a wrench, in this case the pilot purposely shut off an engine. After landing successfully I mentioned to the sim pilot (sitting in the commander left seat, he was not an astronaut) that there were questions about the feasibility of RTLS. He said it seemed pretty straightforward to him. Of course he was not flying through the exhaust plume and all of that, although that is apparently overblown.

Comment: I think your question was enhanced by including the two general scenarios, bad problems vs not so bad or even non-existent problems. No one expects RTLS to guarantee survival if an OMS pod is half blown off and flailing in the wind. But by some accounts even semi-benign situations like not maintaining cabin pressure or faulty sensors shutting down an engine would lean towards unsurvivable if it required RTLS. I don't know how true that is but it helps to differentiate that type of scenario from scenarios where flight hardware is not working right. And abort altitude seems to make a difference.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr it was very dangerous**

I would love to quote a document that says "we compute there was a 57.4356% chance of successfully completing an RTLS abort"...but I'm pretty sure that document does not exist. The NASA human spaceflight program was *incredibly resistant* to doing probabilistic risk analyses on their missions at least for Apollo and Shuttle. They were finally forced to do it for Shuttle  and the results were as [gloomy](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/20110004917/downloads/20110004917.pdf) as you might expect but even then it didn't really address aborts.

Nonetheless I feel justified in saying that RTLS would have been dangerous for two reasons:

**Reason 1:**

*You did not even think about doing an RTLS unless you were already in a very dangerous situation* - one where flying backwards through your own exhaust plume at high Mach numbers seemed like a good idea in comparison. There were two categories of these situations:

*Vehicle Performance*

Which means, one or more of your main engines has failed or become degraded to the point that you cannot make it to any kind of orbit. So if you don't do something, you are going to end up in the Atlantic Ocean in a vehicle that can't survive ditching and that, for most of the program, was equipped with a bail-out system that I would call a band-aid except I do not want to smear the good name of Band-Aids.

It also needs to be mentioned that a main engine failure could be a Very Bad Thing. Those engines were equipped with a controller that monitored various sensors on the engine and would try to shut the engine off if those sensors showed that failure was imminent. But - and you will just have to trust me on this, the numbers come from Rocketdyne and they was argued over endlessly in Ascent Flight Techniques meetings but I don't have those minutes - when the controller was triggered to shut the engine down due to those sensor readings there was a ~33% chance that it would blow up anyway; there was a ~33% chance that it would shut down safely although it would have blown up if it kept running; and there was a ~33% chance that it would have run OK for the full mission, but would shut down safely.

The only actual [in-flight failure leading to shutdown of a main engine](https://www.ibiblio.org/apollo/Shuttle/Reports/Mission%20Reports/STS-51-F%20National%20Space%20Transportation%20System%20Mission%20Report.pdf) was the most benign possible kind: the sensors failed and said there was a problem when the engine was actually running perfectly fine.

So a failed main engine may have shut down nicely, or it may have wreaked all kinds of havoc in the aft compartment. Nonetheless you have to try the RTLS or end up in the Atlantic.

*Systems Problems*

[image]

The reasons for doing an RTLS for systems problems are listed in the [Ascent Checklist](https://archive.org/download/flight-maps-and-charts/ASC-CL-135.pdf) and are at least as scary as main engine problems. Basically they boil down to problems where *a) you are going to die in a very short time if you do not land so it behooves you to get to the ground as quickly as possibly and in this phase of flight that means RTLS or b) you have suffered a failure that means you cannot survive a normal or TAL entry and the heating on RTLS entries is somewhat more benign so you have a better chance in that regard anyway*.

They were:

- You are about to lose all your hydraulic systems, which means you will lose control of the vehicle.
- There is a huge leak in the cabin.
- All of the stuff you use to generate electricity is leaking out, and there are no batteries. When the electricity goes away, you are done.
- All of your heat rejection capability is lost and everything in the Orbiter is going to overheat and fail.
- Two of your three main electrical buses are down which prevents you from closing [big doors](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/18667/6944) that cover holes in the belly heat shield and therefore you will die on a normal or TAL entry. Oh and by the way, this will also cause a main engine to shut down.
- The [outer window pane](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/59723/6944) of one or more of the front windows is broken and pieces are missing. It will not survive a normal or TAL entry and neither will you.

*I hope I have convinced you that the reasons for doing an RTLS are very dangerous in and of themselves.*

**Reason 2:**

*RTLS was completely untested. It was a certified abort, but it was certified by analysis and wind-tunnel testing, and 1970s computer simulation*.

Exactly the same way that nominal ascents and entries were certified and were equally untested for the first launch...and STS-1 had [quite a few bad surprises](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/61050/6944) in store:

- Ignition overpressure from the boosters was underpredicted and caused mechanical damage to propulsion components in the Orbiter
- The plume effects on ascent performance were predicted incorrectly resulting in a significant difference in the ascent trajectory
- The hypersonic pitch trim on entry was incorrectly predicted

Any of these three errors could have resulted in disaster for the first shuttle mission if they had been a bit wronger or the program had been less conservative. It would be ludicrous to claim that the predictions for the RTLS ascent and entry trajectories were any better.

*The unknown errors in analysis and prediction of the RTLS trajectory made it very dangerous.*

**In conclusion, flying on the Shuttle was dangerous anyway (see that PRA I linked); flying an *untested* trajectory because you have already suffered a dangerous failure or failures would have been dangerous squared.**

Comment: Doing hypersonic backflips with an already damaged vehicle strapped to a giant orange bomb does not sound like the greatest idea, indeed. There's of course the famous astronaut quotes we all have heard a thousand times: John Young called it "Russian Roulette" and said it requires "continuous miracles interspersed with acts of God", Mike Mullane called it an "unnatural act of physics", and another considered it busywork for the astronauts while they're waiting to die.

Comment: Would they have flown into their exhaust plume? I think in late RTLS scenarios the pitcharound maneuver occurred well above the Karman line, and still above the USAF line by the time they reversed direction. Even in early RTLS scenarios they continue flying upwards (and downrange) until they have burned excess fuel before beginning the pitcharound. What was the lowest altitude pitcharound might occur? Would the atmosphere be dense enough to slow the exhaust to below vehicle speed? And if so what was the main hazard of that, temperatures higher than parts of the vehicle were designed for?

Comment: @StevePemberton https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19930016866/downloads/19930016866.pdf "a large portion of the hot plume will be forced back to the vehicle due to the vehicle's orientation against the oncoming free stream."

Comment: OrganicMarble - So it seems that the ET was the most vulnerable part of the stack, which of course makes sense. It looks like the report mainly says that for lower altitude RTLS the predictions were inconclusive (even when tossing out Rockwell's apparently rosy data).  While of course inconclusive means that it could be bad, were there any indications that the plume heating would be likely bad?

Comment: @StevePemberton I took it to mean, as you say "inconclusive means that it could be bad".

Comment: The STS-1 type of anomalies would be somewhat expected for the very first powered flight of a unique vehicle with such immense power. But what followed was rapid knowledge gained about Shuttle's performance and handling during (nominal) launch, reentry, and landing. Including some (planned) hot rodding during reentry by Joe Engle on STS-2. And simulator models would now be much more precise. So compared to STS-1 predictions, why would it be ludicrous to claim that the predictions for the RTLS ascent and entry trajectories were any better? Not saying there weren't unknowns, I'm sure there were.

Comment: @StevePemberton you've posted enough verbiage in comments to collate into your own answer and/or followup questions...go for it!

Comment: But I only have questions! Well I'll see what I can come up with (replying to OP, not naming to avoid all comments to this answer getting pushed to chat. I will delete my comments if I post an answer)

Comment: "We've never actually tried it, but it might work, who knows, might as well give it a shot!"

Comment: Was crew medical emergency or any other non-vehicle reason considered a justification for RTLS?

Comment: @ikrase the reasons for calling an ascent abort were spelled out in flight rule a2-51 (page 534 in this pdf: https://archive.org/details/flight_rules_generic/) based on that I'd have to say no. Reading the rationale sections of these rules (-51 and -52) (the text in italics) might cast some light on the thought process.

Comment: [Your comment here](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/10601/195) says that RTLS was routinely executed in sims. Can you characterize how much of your (or the average upper deck astronaut crew's) concern comes from Reason 1 (ship is in trouble) versus Reason 2 (sim isn't realistic)?

Comment: @RussellBorogove in the sims the crew knew that we were not going to kill them  (even simulated death) if they could figure out what we threw at them.  The real world was not so generous. Flying an RTLS in the sim with no mals worked perfectly every time.

Comment: Huh. No Kobayashi Maru scenarios in NASA training?

Comment: @RussellBorogove no, we were not allowed to kill the crew (on purpose). Sometimes it happened but then there were meetings. Anyway, simulate-killing them in a sim would be trivially easy. And they could kill themselves of course.

Comment: I do recall that John Young (often referred to as "the conscience of the Astronaut Office," as he had a habit of "saying the quiet part out loud") was very suspicious of RTLS - didn't seem to trust the numbers. BTW, John was considered to be a very good engineer.